# Alterar cultura do MonthCalendar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, calendar, culture

É possível alterar o formato de data do objeto `MonthCalendar` de uma aplicação WinForms?

Ocorre que a cultura selecionada na estação de um cliente é Polish e isso está causando erro no tratamento de datas da aplicação.

Tentei usar algumas alternativas como:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Mas não tive sucesso, o  calendário mantém o formato de data padrão (configurado no Regional Settings do SO).

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la agora? Veja o [tour] para entender como funciona. Ajudaria muito indicar para todo mundo que a solução foi útil e satisfatória para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

Até onde eu sei esse componente não tem esta capacidade (por alguma falha interna). Ou o usuário muda sua configuração (o componente reconhece o padrão do usuário informado pelo sistema operacional), ou o código precisa usar outro componente. [Um que costumam recomendar está disponível no Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45684/Culture-Aware-Month-Calendar-and-Datepicker), não sei se é bom ou te atende.

Comment: Já tinha ouvido falar e lido sobre o assunto, é infelizmente vou ter que me virar para dar um jeito, o problema é que são muitas interfaces que utilizam o MonthCalendar. obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Bom, aí é uma questão de arquitetura. Nos meus sistemas mudar uma parte não costuma causar problemas deste tipo, sempre tem uma [forma canônica](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101).